# Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'termios'

Tags: python

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

This is the code I have written

Comment: Can you be more specific? In general, people will be more willing to help you with a specific type of problem (and also you avoid getting downvotes) if you post a mcve (minimal complete verifiable example). Please, edit your question to add more information.

Comment: Only use an inner import of pty for Windows compatibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you on windows by any chance? If so, you need to use a Unix based system since Termios is only on Unix and not windows according to [this source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tty.html)

Since termios is an inbuilt python library, If you are on a Unix-based system, just:

```
import termios
```

If this does not work, your python installation is likely broken and you will need to reinstall Python